# Filter DataTable by DateTime (ShortDate)

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm working on a VB.Net project in Visual Studio 2013, and I have a data table full of rows containing ShortDate format strings in a column called "Date Purchased".  I want to filter the data such that all rows that pass through the filter are imported to another data table.

For example, if the minimum filter was "01/01/1750" and the maximum filter was "01/01/2050", a row containing "4/12/1989" in the appropriate column would be imported to a different table.

The filter looks something like this:

```
Dim dateMin As String = "01/01/1750"
dim dateMax As String = "01/01/2050"
Dim dateExpression As String = "Date Purchased >= #" & dateMin & "# and Date Purchased <= #" & DateTime.Parse(dateMax.Text) & "#"


Dim dateFilter() = oldTable.Select(dateExpression)
For Each r As DataRow In dateFilter
   newTable.ImportRow(r)
Next
```

My problem is that I get the error message "Additional information: Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Purchased' operator." and no rows are imported.  dateExpression looks something like this:

`"Date Purchased >= #1/1/1700# and Date Purchased <= #12/31/3000#"`

Why doesn't this work?  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT**: The problem was completely resolved by using [Date Purchased] instead of "Date Purchased". Thanks!

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Access?  Access uses the # delimiter, but SQL Server uses ' (single quote).  You'd get that type of error if you're using SQL Server with #.

Comment: Neither; I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Are you using a database in the backend?  Or is this all just in memory?

Comment: Good God!  "I have a data table full of rows **containing** ShortDate format **strings**".  **WHY**?!  If the data represents dates then populate the DataTable with actual dates, not strings.  You can't filter by date if the data is text.  It's that simple.

Comment: Not sure, I'm using the DataTable.Select() function on a DataTable object.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, do you think I should try to convert the strings back into DateTime objects?  And is there a way to use the DataTable.Select function if I did?

Comment: @user3474146, no, I think that they should never have been converted to strings in the first place.  Do you store your numbers as text?  I'll wager not, so why store dates as text?  Dates and times should be stored in a database as a data type specific to dates and times and they should be used in your application code as DateTimes and/or TimeSpans at all times too.  The only time format is an issue is for display or serialisation so that's the only time they should be converted to text.  Once your DataTable contains Dates, you can compare them to other Dates and filter by date.

Comment: Assuming that your DataTable contains Dates and not Strings, the code to filter should look something like this: `Dim dateExpression As String = String.Format("Date Purchased >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# and DatePurchased <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", dateMin, dateMax` where the two variables are also type Date.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, the reason the rows contain strings like "05/28/1970" is because the application I am working on exports the DataTable to a .csv file.  I'm a beginner at VB.net and I don't have a lot of experience.  The code you gave does not work - I think because where the syntax may be correct, I receive the same syntax error.  I think it's having problems filtering strings like "05/28/1970" when they should be formatted like "1970-05-28".  Is there a way to parse these strings in the DataTable for the purposes of selecting them with DataTable.Select(dateExpression)?

Comment: you cannot use a date filter on string data because it is not a date. his code was prefaced with `Assuming that your DataTable contains Dates and not Strings`

Comment: @plutonix, I have also tried using DateTime.Parse() to no avail.

Comment: It **DOES NOT MATTER** that your application exports the data to a CSV.  Your DataTable should contain Dates and you should be converting those Dates to Strings **WHEN AND ONLY WHEN** you export the data, just as you would do with numbers.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` is to covert string data to a Date variable...it wont help with your filter. the column in the data source needs to be a Date type in order to use Date filtering

Comment: Your syntax error is actually unrelated to the dates and is a result of the fact that your column name has a space in it.  You should avoid using spaces and other special characters in identifiers, i.e. you should use "DatePurchased" as the column name.  If that is not possible for whatever reason, you must escape the column name in code, i.e. use "[Date Purchased]".

Comment: @jmcilhinney, using "Date Purchased" instead of "[Date Purchased]" turned out to be the **ONLY** problem with the filter.  Thank you very much for your help and advice!

Comment: If your DataTable contains Strings and you're using Dates in the filter, one of them has to be converted to the other type in order for a comparison to be done.  Do you know which one is converted?  How about you just do it properly in the first place and use Dates where the data represents dates?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, the strings in the DataTable are formatted in ShortDate format (i.e. "05/28/1984"), and the filter looks something like "[Date Purchased] >= #01/31/1800 00:00:00# AND [Date Purchased] <= #01/31/2050 00:00:00#".  It works!  I have been using VB.Net for two weeks, and I am still learning, so thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by using [Date Purchased] instead of "Date Purchased".